# Creating A Google Sheets Query From Two Tabs

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm creating a google sheet where I want to display a Query on Sheet A, and have it look through data on Sheet B.

My sheets tabs names are the following:

Sheet A = List

Sheet B = Master Database

Currently, I'm using the following formula on Sheet A:

```
=SELECT(Sheet'Master Database'!A:K, WHERE 'Master Database'!C CONTAINS ‘”,'List'!B5,”‘”)
```

However, I'm getting *Error, Formula parse error.* Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Are those quotes the same type in Excel, or the result of a copy/paste? Some of those `"` marks look to be a different character, perhaps that's causing the issue? Replace the `”` and `”` with `"` (and `‘` with `'`).

Answer (score 0):

On Google Sheets, there isn't a built-in function called SELECT. To learn what are the available functions see [Google Sheets Functions List](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en). Maybe you are looking for [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

By the other hand the references and quotes are wrong. See [Reference data from other sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en)